# How to organize Controllers and Views into namespaces or subfolders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application. The app is broken up into a dozen "sections", each of which has multiple tasks the user can perform. Many of these subtasks deserve their own controller, I don't like "kitchen sink" controllers.

I want to organize my controllers by adding a namespace hierarchy:

Foo.SubFoo1.List

Foo.SubFoo2.List

etc.

I figured out how to create the routing rules, I just don't know how to wire up the correct view. **The MVC framework doesn't factor my controller's parent namespace into the algorithm when it looks for the view:**

Foo.SubFoo1.List ==> MVC looks for a view **Views\SubFoo1\List.aspx**, but I *want* it to look for **Views\Foo\SubFoo1\List.aspx**

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is "override the default ViewEngine," but it sounds like you're really looking for ["areas."](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/11/05/app-areas-in-aspnet-mvc-take-2/)

Comment: Can't wait for MVC 2.0 :)

Thanks!